# Combine HTML5 tags for quote with image and author

Tags: html, semantic-markup

After searching some resources, I ended up creating this equivalence:

```
<blockquote>

  <p>Nulla venenatis ac orci at placerat. Vivamus quam odio, sagittis vitae dui in, faucibus euismod metus. Vivamus purus sem, dictum vel egestas sit amet, facilisis ac tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Elis mauris, luctus in risus et, volutpat malesuada mito.</p>
  <figure>
    <img src="#" alt="John Doe">
    <figcaption>
        <small>John Doe</small>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

</blockquote>
```

For this result:

[image]

Is it correct to use on this case `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`?

Is it better to use footer or small for the author? Both seem valid.

Comment: Your questions on SO should ask for specific answers to specific problems, not opinions of code or design. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: `figure` and `figcaption` are for image content and legend, not for author...

Comment: @Rob absolutely. Edited.

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman is this not an image content and a legend about what the image contains?

Comment: @Biomehanika I'm with you, figure and figcaption seems valid for this. Is an image and its caption. I don't know the problem that describes cyril.

Comment: Ok Sorry, I thought we could only use it in articles for example, for SEO referecement but not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're following [W3C HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element), which allows attribution to be placed within a `blockquote` element, you need to use a `footer`:

> Attribution for the quotation, [if any,] may be be *[sic]* placed inside the `blockquote` element, but must be within a `cite` element for in-text attributions or within a `footer` element.

You can still use a `figure` element as you are doing, though; you just need to put it in a `footer`.

Your use of the `small` element is inappropriate, since the author name isn't what most would consider "fine print" [for the purposes of `small`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element). The author name is marked up using `cite` (again, if you're following W3C HTML5):

```
<blockquote>

  <p>Nulla venenatis ac orci at placerat. Vivamus quam odio, sagittis vitae dui in, faucibus euismod metus. Vivamus purus sem, dictum vel egestas sit amet, facilisis ac tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Elis mauris, luctus in risus et, volutpat malesuada mito.</p>
  <footer>
    <figure>
      <img src="#" alt="John Doe">
      <figcaption><cite>John Doe</cite></figcaption>
    </figure>
  </footer>

</blockquote>
```

If you're following [WHATWG HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-blockquote-element), then it forbids attribution to be placed within a `blockquote`; in this case, simply move the `figure` out of the `blockquote`.